# Leak canary showing leak in fragment root layout while using webview in item of viewpager2

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, leakcanary

I am using webview as a view in item of viewpager 2 when i am browsing the app the memory usage in profiler reaches 1gb very soon currently using best practices on viewbinding.
code->

@AndroidEntryPoint
class ArticleDetailFragment : BaseFragment() {

```
private var _binding:  FragmentArticleDetailBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
@Inject
lateinit var fePreference: FESharedPreference


override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentArticleDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view

    }


override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    binding.vpArticle.adapter=null
    _binding = null
    articleDetailAdapter=null


}
```